# How to make sure a Drawer Navigation is completely removed when I navigate to another BottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-drawer

I have a BottomTabNavigator which, contains another BottomTabNavigator and two DrawerNavigator s.

One of the DrawerNavigators represents the authenticated state. I just implemented a log out button in this drawerNavigation. The button purges the redux state and navigates to the BottomTabNavigator, more specifically, to the Login route of the Welcome navigator.

However, once in the Welcome Navigato after logout, the authenticated Drawer shows up when I try to navigate to another route of the BottomTabNavigator.

I am not sure why this is happening. When I refresh the expo project, I realize that indeed the application is in a non-authenticated state.

Is there a way to make sure the Authenticated Drawer Navigator does not show up when I log out ?

Here is my main navigator:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  Button,
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  DrawerItems,

 } from 'react-navigation';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Welcome from './screens/Welcome';
import Register from './screens/RegisterScreen';
import Login from './screens/LoginScreen';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import Events from './screens/Events';
import Board from './screens/Board';
import HomePage from './screens/HomePage';
import SettingsScreen from './screens/BusinessSettings';
import BusinessEvents from './screens/BusinessEvents';
import EventListings from './screens/EventListings';
import BusinessListings from './screens/BusinessListings';
import Business from './screens/Business';
import BusinessForm from './screens/BusinessForm';
import EventForm from './screens/EventForm';
import Logout from './screens/Logout';
import { persistor, store } from './store';


const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Welcome: createBottomTabNavigator({
      Welcome: Welcome,
      Login: Login,
      Register: Register,
      Board: Board,
    }),

    Home: createDrawerNavigator({
      Home: {
        screen: Home,
      },
      Events: {
        screen: Events,
      },
      Business: {
        screen: Business
      }
    }),
    HomePage: createDrawerNavigator({
      HomePage: {
        screen: HomePage,
      },
      Settings: {
        screen: SettingsScreen,
      },
      EventListings: {
        screen: EventListings
      },

      EventForm: {
        screen: EventForm
      },

      BusinessEvents: {
        screen: BusinessEvents
      },
      BusinessListings: {
        screen: BusinessListings
      },
      NewBusiness: {
        screen: BusinessForm
      },
      Business: {
        screen: Business
      }
    }, {

      contentComponent: (props) => (
        <View style={{ flex:1 }}>
         <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
           <DrawerItems {...props} />
           <TouchableOpacity style={{  flexDirection: 'row', marginLeft: '8%', paddingTop: '2%' }} onPress={ async () => {
             await AsyncStorage.clear();
             await persistor.purge();
             props.navigation.navigate("Welcome");
           }}>
               <Ionicons name="ios-log-out-outline" size={24} color="#053541" /><Text style={{ marginLeft: '14%', fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black' }}>Log Out</Text>
           </TouchableOpacity>
         </SafeAreaView>
   </View>
     ),
     drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
     drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
     drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'

    })
  },
  {
   headerMode: 'none',
   navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
        tabBarVisible: false,
        headerVisible: false,
        headerMode: 'none',
  },
    tabBarVisible: false,
    swipeEnabled: false,
    animationEnabled: false,
    lazy: true,
    transitionConfig: () => ({
      transitionSpec: {
        duration: 0,
      },
    }),

    /* Other configuration remains unchanged */
  }
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
          <MainNavigator />
        </PersistGate>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
};
```